# Remove element that contains special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

list = ['b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'billy29665@', 'bIllY93$2', 'bilLy553']

Remove any element that contains special character. 
So the output I wanted is

['bilLy553']

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you just wanted the last element then use list[-1]....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.Here we are filtering out strings which only contain alphabets and numbers.I believe this can serve your purpose.

```
 newl = [s for s in list if s.isalnum()]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helps me a lot!

Comment: "你好".isalnum() returns True, i.e., isalnum() cannot deal with special chars, how to modify this to keep just English letters. Specifically, only keep elements made up with '[a-zA-Z]' , filter out other non-English letters.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can use `filter` and `isalnum`

```
>>> lst = ['b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'b!lly932', 'billy29665@', 'bIllY93$2', 'bilLy553']
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), lst)
['bilLy553']
```

Comment: @Jenny Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.